# ASP.NET Core Identity with ClearDB MySql

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am trying to establish User Identity in my ASP.NET Core 1 Application, which hosted in Azure. Also, I have got an ClearDB MySQL DataBase.

And I cannot find a right way to connect my application to the MySQL db. There are some pages ([one](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-using-mysql-storage-with-an-entityframework-mysql-provider), [two](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-using-mysql-storage-with-an-entityframework-mysql-provider)), which explains how to connect to MySql, but they all work with ASP.NET Web Application, not ASP.NET Core, which is slight different (for instance, does not contain System.Configuration library).

Maybe someone already managed it?

Answer (score 2):

Seems that a DB Provider is still incoming for MySQL. See [here](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/providers/index.html).

Comment: I saw it, thanks. But i thought that someone already found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL provider now exists however it is in pre-release. See [here](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/providers/mysql/).  I have been having a few issues with it so far, mostly relating to migrating Core Identity from SQL Server.  But for the most part it seems to work well.